# In which output (0 or 1) a transaction fee is included?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

I need to know, if I have to pay a transaction fee, in which output of the transaction the fee is included? is it output 0 or output 1?
I suppose that normally there is only 2 outputs for a transaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither.

The transaction fee is the difference in value between the inputs and the outputs of a transaction.